# How to disable SwiftUI ScrollView clipping

Tags: ios, swiftui

See the following sample code:

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    HStack(spacing: 20) {
        ForEach(0 ..< 12) { index in
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .shadow(radius: 20)
        }
    }
}
```

This sample code will result in a horizontal `ScrollView`
with `Rectangle` as elements.

However, as it seems the ScrollView actually clips it's content
so any shadow on the top and bottom will be clipped.

Is there any way to disable automatic clipping by the scrollview
or another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Shadow won't affect the frame of the `Rectangle`. So, try to add padding to the Rectangle, so the Shadow will be still visible, by increasing the frame size of the Rectangle including shadow..

```
ForEach(0 ..< 12) { index in
    Rectangle()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .shadow(radius: 20)
        .padding(20) //<< Padding here for the radius
}
```